# R – Replicate/Automate scatterplots for each string group in column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe (170 observation and 3 columns) like so:

```
site_names <- c("WS1", "WS1", "WS2", "WS2", "WS3", "WS3")
x <- c(.15, .20, .17, .16, .20, .22)
y <- c(.026, .031, .045, .087, .09, .033)

df <- data.frame(site_names, x, y)
```

and I have a simple ggplot formula I can run for each site_name where I plot x and y accordingly:

```
df %>% 
filter(site_names == "") %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
geom_point() +
labs(x = "Discharge", y = "Stage")
```

What I would like is to automate these plots and generate 26 separate plots by site_name and save them all to a PDF

Here is what I have tried:

```
scatter_expl = function(x, y) {
 ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y) ) +
      geom_point() +
      theme_bw() +
      labs(x = "Discharge", y = "Stage")
}

plots = map(df, ~scatter_expl())

plots
```

But this runs through the whole dataframe, returns a list and produces all scatters on the same plot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVBhf.png! How do I group by site and return individual graphs?

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Okay, I think I fixed it it now - sorry I forgot to add the string syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may need to `group_by`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
out <- df %>%
    group_by(site_names) %>%
    summarise(plot = list(ggplot(cur_data(), aes(x = x, y = y)) +
                geom_point() +
                labs(x = "Discharge", y = "Stage")+   
                ggtitle(sprintf('Plot for %s', cur_group()$site_names))))
```

-output

```
> out
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  site_names plot  
  <chr>      <list>
1 WS1        <gg>  
2 WS2        <gg>  
3 WS3        <gg>
```

-save the output as pdf

```
ggsave(file.path(getwd(), "plot.pdf"), 
      marrangeGrob(out$plot, nrow = 1, ncol = 1), device = "pdf")
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(site_names = c("WS1", "WS1", "WS2", "WS2", "WS3", 
"WS3"), x = c(0.15, 0.2, 0.17, 0.16, 0.2, 0.22), y = c(0.026, 
0.031, 0.045, 0.087, 0.09, 0.033)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Okay that group_by/summarise works to return a list. How do I go about plotting all the elements in that list as separate graphs?

Comment: @ForevaR- do you want a single pdf or different

Comment: ideally all of my individual graphs in one pdf!

Comment: Thanks - nevermind about the typo, I just do not have that function!

Comment: @ForevaR- it is not.  I loaded the `gridExtra` package

Comment: @ForevaR- you need to load `library(gridExtra)` if it is not installed, you can install with `install.packages`

Comment: One last question - how do I get each corresponding site_name as the title for each graph?

Comment: @akrun . Master could you please check my answer here. I want to iterate through each list element and make the scatterplots from a function. but it is empty. Many thanks

Comment: @ForevaR- it is already updated in the code.  Maybe you were using my old code

Answer (score 1):

Updated with the help of dear @akrun:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)
library(gridExtra)

# create list of df by site_names
dflist <- df %>% 
  group_split(site_names)

# create a function to plot 
scatter_fun = function(dat) {
  ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    geom_point() +
    theme_bw() +
    labs(x = "Discharge", y = "Stage")
}

# iterate through each list element and apply function (many thanks to @akrun for his help)
p <- map(dflist, ~scatter_fun(.x))

# save all in one pdf
ggsave(
  filename = "plots.pdf", 
  plot = marrangeGrob(p, nrow=2, ncol=2), 
  width = 7.5, height = 4.5
)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you need the x and y arguments, in the function if it is fixed .. i.e. `function(dat) {ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) + `

Comment: then you need only `map(dflist, ~ scatter_fun(.x))`.  your `scatter_fun(df` is incorrect as it uses the whole data 'df'.  it should be `.x` which is the data.frame/tibble element of the `list`

Comment: oh this is better . good good.  so now I have to save it. perfect i will try.